# Does the Google URL shortener have a feature similar to Bitly's HTTP request?

Tags: google-url-shortener, goo.gl, url-shortener

I'm using Bitly currently to shorten links via HTTP request. I'd like to do the same through the Goo.gl service because it's free. I can't seem to find any documentation from Google on such a setup. Here's what I'm using with Bitly.

https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=MyApiToken&format=txt&longUrl=http://MyWebLink.com

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the [Google URL Shortener API](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started)